# PHP 5.3 and interface \ArrayAccess

Tags: arrays, php

I'm now working on a project and I have one class that implements the ArrayAccess interface.

Howewer, I'm getting an error that says that my implementation:

*must be compatible with that of ArrayAccess::offsetSet().*

My implementation looks like this:

```
public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
  if (!is_string($offset)) {
    throw new \LogicException("...");
  }
  $this->params[$offset] = $value;
}
```

So, to me it looks like my implementation is correct. Any idea what is wrong? Thanks very much!

The class look like this:

```
class HttpRequest implements \ArrayAccess {
  // tons of private variables, methods for working
  // with current http request etc. Really nothing that
  // could interfere with that interface.

  // ArrayAccess implementation

  public function offsetExists($offset) {
    return isset ($this->params[$offset]);
  }

  public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset ($this->params[$offset]) ? $this->params[$offset] : NULL;
  }

  public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
     if (!is_string($offset)) {
      throw new \LogicException("You can only assing to params using specified key.");
     }
     $this->params[$offset] = $value;
  }

  public function offsetUnset($offset) {
    unset ($this->params[$offset]);
  }
}
```

---

The class look like this:

```
class HttpRequest implements \ArrayAccess {
  // tons of private variables, methods for working
  // with current http request etc. Really nothing that
  // could interfere with that interface.

  // ArrayAccess implementation

  public function offsetExists($offset) {
    return isset ($this->params[$offset]);
  }

  public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset ($this->params[$offset]) ? $this->params[$offset] : NULL;
  }

  public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
     if (!is_string($offset)) {
      throw new \LogicException("You can only assing to params using specified key.");
     }
     $this->params[$offset] = $value;
  }

  public function offsetUnset($offset) {
    unset ($this->params[$offset]);
  }
}
```

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: The line with class declaration (class X implements \ArrayAccess).

Comment: It could help if you provide the rest of the class (or a shortened version of it).

Comment: What happens if you stop it throwing an exception?

Comment: Is your class declaration inside a namespace? e.g. do you have a `namespace My\Namespace;` declaration at the top of the file? if not, you shouldn't need to qualify ArrayAccess. You could also try "use"ing `ArrayAccess` instead of fully qualifying it. This seems like a weird error, so I'm just throwing things out there...

Comment: Why is it `\ArrayAccess`? Whats up with the backslash?

Comment: I have my class in custom namespace (Web/Http). That's why there's \ArrayAccess (the leading \ means referencing a class/interface/function in global namespace). Good idea with useing \ArrayAccess, I'll try it once I can. Btw, thanx for all answers.

Comment: Really nothing that produces the error with the code you've pasted: http://eval.in/2184 Also your question is a little older, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your `namespace` or `use` directives in the top of the file make it look for the wrong `ArrayAccess` interface to be compatible with. Can't tell for sure without those directives though.

**In general:**

Your own namespaces should not begin or end with a backslash:

*Use:*
    `namespace Web\Http;`

***Don't*** *use something like:*
    `namespace \Web\Http;` or `namespace \Web\Http\;`

For every class and interface you reference in your file, add a `use` directive:

```
namespace MyProject;

use MyLibrary\BaseClass; // note no backslash before the namespace name
use \ArrayAccess;
use \Iterator;
use \Countable;

class MyClass extends BaseClass implements ArrayAccess, Iterator, Countable
{
    /* Your implementation goes here as normal */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that catches my eye here:

```
 public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset ($this->params[$offset]) ? $this->params[$offset] : NULL;
  }
```

Perhaps replacing it with:

```
 public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return (isset ($this->params[$offset]) ? $this->params[$offset] : NULL);
  }
```

would get the trick done.

It could also be a syntax error that drags on from the part of the code you haven't pasted.

Comment: Thanks, but although this is surely correct and it improves the code readability, it doesn't help me with this problem.

Comment: Good idea with that syntax error, but after removing the implementation the class works perfectly again.

Comment: Your code works fine here. Pasted it into a file and ran it from the command line using: php test.php. It has to be something in the part of the code you haven't pasted.

Comment: Hey, what version of PHP are you using? PHP 5.3.X?

Comment: I've just did the same, with the implementation commented out, and it worked. The code above is fine.

It should be fine anyway. I don't say that Netbeans 6.8 IDE is completely reliable, but it doesn't report any syntax error.

Comment: parenthesis here make no difference, everything between the `return` and the `?` is the condition, wether you put them in parenthesis or not. (it might add to the readability somewhat though)